# Commerce module in not drupal commerce

Tags: commerce

I have a website, built as a non Drupal commerce website. I want to add functionality to my website so customers can buy books, and add checkout page and cart.
I mean add commerce functionality in a not Drupal commerce site.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Yes that is possible. Download the modules from: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce

You can not install the install profile (https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) on top of an existing Drupal website.

Answer (score 3):

You can just install commerce on top of a non-commerce drupal site in the beginning. Commerce for drupal core it is just another module that adds fields, views, rules, content types, functionality and so on.